# Dictionary using int key and Delegate can not contain inline initialization

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a Dictionary which contains functions and identified by an int.

I currently have this working but was going to initialize inline but after doing so I get an error:
*A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'name'.*

Declared as:

```
public Dictionary<int, Delegate> delay = new Dictionary<int, Delegate>()
    {
        {0, new Func<IndicatorState, bool>(Proc) }
    };
```

Function Im using:

```
public bool Proc(IndicatorState _old)
    {
        if(_old == IndicatorState.locked)
        {
            return !acpin;
        }
        return acpin;
    }
```

The IndicatorState is an enum which is declared in a separate class but I don't have issues using or access it. I have done research on the issue and can just add it all to the constructor of the class which solves my issue but I don't quite understand why it can only be done this way.

Sorry if I have been vague, first time posting on here. I will clarify anything that anyone needs. I can live with adding to the dictionary via the constructor this is just more to understand the issue.

Comment: The issue is that `Proc` is not static, so to use it you'd need an instance which you do not have during initialization of the field.  You can make it static if `acpin` is static or by changing it to take `acpin` as an argument.

Comment: Proc is an instance member function, you cannot do it like that, you dont show what class it belongs to but you need an instance of its containing class. You probably need a lambda

Comment: Another way to think about it is that you can't access `this` in an initializer.  Naturally, trying to access an instance method implicitly requires access to `this`.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, that clarifies everything.